# release.keystore of Unity App for Android has a different SHA1 Fingerprint

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keystore, google-play-console

i have encountered a strange issue with my release key. The first alpha version of my Game was successful uploaded to Google Play Console, but the second one was rejected from uploading, because the fingerprint was not the same. I have controlled the SHA-1 >Fingerprint of my release.keystore in Terminal and it gave me the correct SHA-1 key that was required by Google Play Console.

Made with Unity 2021.3.5f1

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you used same keystore file on android build?

Comment: Yes i have, it was also alredy in Unity Player Settings stored